# Incremental MySQL backup to Amazon S3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Looking at this now. Any script recommendation will do. Using Rails app too.

The difference with current scripts around is it's a full backup, my MySQL database files are like 120MB+ for now, which will increase overtime. So I wonder if there is any incremental method around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recent [thread](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/223306) on mysql.com discusses it.

Basically, you have to set the server up to do binary logging and set a threshold for each log to whatever size increment you prefer for backing up. Then just upload a complete backup once and start your binary logging from that point forward.  Then just upload each log once it is closed and a new one is opened.

It is more complicated than that but I think that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it's too complicated. Probably will just do an automated full backup.